# Loader still remains loading even after the successful action

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

While adding image into a field , even after the process completed the loader remains still loading. I have submitted the form using ajax.can i get what would be the reason for the unlimited loading? My code is below

```
  $('.port_load').waitMe({
        effect: 'win8',
        text: 'Please Wait...',
        bg: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.85)',
        color: '#000',
        maxSize: '',
        source: 'img.svg',
        onClose: function() {}
});
```

here is my full code for submission

```
  $('#port_form').submit(function(e){    
e.preventDefault();    
$('.port_load').waitMe({
        effect: 'win8',
        text: 'Please Wait...',
        bg: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.85)',
        color: '#000',
        maxSize: '',
        source: 'img.svg',
        onClose: function() {}
}); 
if($('#img1').val()!='' && $('#p_img').val()==''){//for editing
    $.ajax({
                url:'../api_fle/port',
                method:'POST',
                data:{u_id:$('#uId').val(),title:$('#p_title').val(),desc:$('#p_description').val(),
                    link:$('#img1').val(),pId:$('#p_id').val()},
                success:function(data){
                      $('.port_load').waitMe('hide');                          
                    if(data==0){
                        $('#wrng').html('<p style="text-align: center; color:red;">Something went Wrong! Try again.</p>');
                    }else{
                                $('#wrng').html('');
                                $('#myModal5').modal('hide');
                                $("#p_img").replaceWith($("#p_img").val('').clone(true));
                                $('#p_title').val('');
                                $('#p_description').val('');
                                $('#p_id').val('');
                                $('#img1').val('');
                        swal({   
                            title: "Success",   
                            text: "Successfully Inserted",   
                            timer: 1000,   
                            showConfirmButton: false
                        });

                        on_load();
                    } 
                }
            });
}else{// adding new
    $.ajax({
        url:'../api_fle/img_upload',
        method:'POST',
        data:  new FormData(this),
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData:false,
        success:function(data){ 
            if(data==0){
                $('.port_load').waitMe('hide');             
                $('#wrng').html('<p style="text-align: center; color:red;">Something went Wrong! Try again</p>');
            }else if(data==1){
                $('.port_load').waitMe('hide');             
                $('#wrng').html('<p style="text-align: center; color:red;">Upload Image only!</p>');
            }else{                  
                $('#wrng').html("");
                var link="http://www.udyomitra.com/photos/"+$('#uId').val()+"/gallery/"+data;

                $.ajax({
                    url:'../api_fle/port',
                    method:'POST',
                    data:{u_id:$('#uId').val(),title:$('#p_title').val(),desc:$('#p_description').val(),
                        link:link,pId:$('#p_id').val()},
                    success:function(data){

                         $('.port_load').waitMe('hide');    
                        if(data==0){
                            $('#wrng').html('<p style="text-align: center; color:red;">Something went Wrong! Try again</p>');
                        }else{
                            $('#wrng').html("");
                            $('#myModal5').modal('hide'); 
                                $("#p_img").replaceWith($("#p_img").val('').clone(true));
                                $('#p_title').val('');
                                $('#p_description').val('');
                                $('#p_id').val('');
                                $('#img1').val('');   

                            swal({   
                                title: "Success",   
                                text: "Successfully Inserted",   
                                timer: 1000,   
                                showConfirmButton: false 
                            });
                            on_load();
                        } 
                    }
                });
            }

        }   
    });
}


});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
$('.port_load').waitMe('hide');
```

More specifically to your problem

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).ajaxStart(function(){
        $('.port_load').waitMe({
            effect: 'win8',
            text: 'Please Wait...',
            bg: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.85)',
            color: '#000',
            maxSize: '',
            source: 'img.svg',
            onClose: function() {}
        }); 
    });
    $(document).ajaxStop(function(){
        $('.port_load').waitMe('hide');
    });


    $('#port_form').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();        
        if ($('#img1').val() != '' && $('#p_img').val() == '') { //for editing
            $.ajax({
                url: '../api_fle/port',
                method: 'POST',
                data: {
                    u_id: $('#uId').val(),
                    title: $('#p_title').val(),
                    desc: $('#p_description').val(),
                    link: $('#img1').val(),
                    pId: $('#p_id').val()
                },
                success: function(data) {                    
                    if (data == 0) {
                        $('#wrng').html('<p style="text-align: center; color:red;">Something went Wrong! Try again.</p>');
                    } else {
                        $('#wrng').html('');
                        $('#myModal5').modal('hide');
                        $("#p_img").replaceWith($("#p_img").val('').clone(true));
                        $('#p_title').val('');
                        $('#p_description').val('');
                        $('#p_id').val('');
                        $('#img1').val('');
                        swal({
                            title: "Success",
                            text: "Successfully Inserted",
                            timer: 1000,
                            showConfirmButton: false
                        });
                        on_load();
                    }
                }
            });
        } else { // adding new
            $.ajax({
                url: '../api_fle/img_upload',
                method: 'POST',
                data: new FormData(this),
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function(data) {
                    if (data == 0) {                        
                        $('#wrng').html('<p style="text-align: center; color:red;">Something went Wrong! Try again</p>');
                    } else if (data == 1) {                        
                        $('#wrng').html('<p style="text-align: center; color:red;">Upload Image only!</p>');
                    } else {
                        $('#wrng').html("");
                        var link = "http://www.udyomitra.com/photos/" + $('#uId').val() + "/gallery/" + data;
                        $.ajax({
                            url: '../api_fle/port',
                            method: 'POST',
                            data: {
                                u_id: $('#uId').val(),
                                title: $('#p_title').val(),
                                desc: $('#p_description').val(),
                                link: link,
                                pId: $('#p_id').val()
                            },
                            success: function(data) {          
                                if (data == 0) {
                                    $('#wrng').html('<p style="text-align: center; color:red;">Something went Wrong! Try again</p>');
                                } else {
                                    $('#wrng').html("");
                                    $('#myModal5').modal('hide');
                                    $("#p_img").replaceWith($("#p_img").val('').clone(true));
                                    $('#p_title').val('');
                                    $('#p_description').val('');
                                    $('#p_id').val('');
                                    $('#img1').val('');
                                    swal({
                                        title: "Success",
                                        text: "Successfully Inserted",
                                        timer: 1000,
                                        showConfirmButton: false
                                    });
                                    on_load();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });

});
```

[Reference](https://github.com/vadimsva/waitMe)

Comment: let me try it :-)

Comment: Can you check this code.May be its my mistake of applying your code inside this code

Comment: I have used your code and the loader stopped after loading for a few seconds. But the modal box doesn't hide and sweet alert message didn't show after successful submission

Comment: Assuming that your code in success callback is correct, I think you are getting error from server side and this does not execute your success callback function. Make sure you are not getting error from PHP side. You can check it in console.

Comment: thnak you the error was from server side :-) solved (Y)

Comment: Thank you SohelAhmedM ... error was really from server side

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to remove you're loader in a different event handler like ajaxComplete() or ajaxError() you can chain them after the success handler;

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).ajaxStart(function(){
    $('.port_load').waitMe({
        effect: 'win8',
        text: 'Please Wait...',
        bg: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.85)',
        color: '#000',
        maxSize: '',
        source: 'img.svg',
        onClose: function() {}
    }); 
});
$(document).ajaxStop(function(){
    $('.port_load').waitMe('hide');
});


$('#port_form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();        
    if ($('#img1').val() != '' && $('#p_img').val() == '') { //for editing
        $.ajax({
            url: '../api_fle/port',
            method: 'POST',
            data: {
                u_id: $('#uId').val(),
                title: $('#p_title').val(),
                desc: $('#p_description').val(),
                link: $('#img1').val(),
                pId: $('#p_id').val()
            },
            success: function(data) {                    
                if (data == 0) {
                    $('#wrng').html('<p style="text-align: center; color:red;">Something went Wrong! Try again.</p>');
                } else {
                    $('#wrng').html('');
                    $('#myModal5').modal('hide');
                    $("#p_img").replaceWith($("#p_img").val('').clone(true));
                    $('#p_title').val('');
                    $('#p_description').val('');
                    $('#p_id').val('');
                    $('#img1').val('');
                    swal({
                        title: "Success",
                        text: "Successfully Inserted",
                        timer: 1000,
                        showConfirmButton: false
                    });

                    on_load();
                }
            },
            complete : function(){},
            error : function(){}
        });
    } else { // adding new
        $.ajax({
            url: '../api_fle/img_upload',
            method: 'POST',
            data: new FormData(this),
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(data) {
                if (data == 0) {                        
                    $('#wrng').html('<p style="text-align: center; color:red;">Something went Wrong! Try again</p>');
                } else if (data == 1) {                        
                    $('#wrng').html('<p style="text-align: center; color:red;">Upload Image only!</p>');
                } else {
                    $('#wrng').html("");
                    var link = "http://www.udyomitra.com/photos/" + $('#uId').val() + "/gallery/" + data;
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '../api_fle/port',
                        method: 'POST',
                        data: {
                            u_id: $('#uId').val(),
                            title: $('#p_title').val(),
                            desc: $('#p_description').val(),
                            link: link,
                            pId: $('#p_id').val()
                        },
                        success: function(data) {          
                            if (data == 0) {
                                $('#wrng').html('<p style="text-align: center; color:red;">Something went Wrong! Try again</p>');
                            } else {
                                $('#wrng').html("");
                                $('#myModal5').modal('hide');
                                $("#p_img").replaceWith($("#p_img").val('').clone(true));
                                $('#p_title').val('');
                                $('#p_description').val('');
                                $('#p_id').val('');
                                $('#img1').val('');
                                swal({
                                    title: "Success",
                                    text: "Successfully Inserted",
                                    timer: 1000,
                                    showConfirmButton: false
                                });
                                on_load();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }
});

});
```